Error 500 en swagger
Buen día, estoy aprendiendo a hacer una Web APIs RESTful ASP.NET Core8 para un proyecto y me aparece un error 500 en swagger, lo único que me marca rojo es en user-agent y content-length, agradecería que me ayudaran a saber como se puede resolver ya que llevo un tiempo con este error.



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! un error 500 no es problema de swagger, es justamente problema de tu codigo.. es mas.. en todo ese choclo verde que ves ahi, esta la causa del problema... eso es lo que habria que ver, junto con el codigo que causa el error.. esto de aca, no es un error..
